# Using write() in Python and Python turtle

Tags: python, prompt, turtle-graphics

I want to use an input parameter in my Python code, but instead of being asked in the Python editor toolbox, the user should be prompted in the Python Turtle Graphics window. I believe that this should be done by built-in write(), but I have no idea how to implement it.

Comment: Please consider adding a code sample, or revising the one you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. Good luck with your code!

Answer (score -2):

"Write" is used for the turtle to write something in the window. You can not currently have an input in the turtle window, unless you code it all yourself.